# SQL GROUPBY & SUM OF A COLUMN

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with the below structure

```
+------------+--------+------------------+-----+
|    E_DATE    | CLIENT |       TIME       | INS |
+------------+--------+------------------+-----+
| 2015-06-04 | comA   | 0.00478515625    |  a1 |
| 2015-06-04 | comA   | 0.0025390625     |  a1 |
| 2015-06-04 | comA   | 0.0              | a1  |
| 2015-06-04 | comA   | 0.0              | a1  |
| 2015-06-04 | comB   | 0.0115234375     | a2  |
| 2015-06-04 | comB   | 1.953125E-4      | a2  |
| 2015-06-04 | comB   | 0.0103515625     | a3  |
| 2015-06-04 | comB   | 0.0              | a3  |
| 2015-06-05 | comA   | 0.00478515625    | a4  |
| 2015-06-05 | comA   | 0.0025390625     | a4  |
| 2015-06-05 | comA   | 0.0              | a1  |
| 2015-06-05 | comA   | 0.0              | a2  |
| 2015-06-05 | comB   | 0.010351         | a1  |
| 2015-06-05 | comB   | 0.05625          | a1  |
+------------+--------+------------------+-----+
```

I am looking to get the following output -

```
+------------+--------+-----+-----------------------------------------------------------+ 
|    E_DATE    | CLIENT | INS |                        TOTAL_TIME                         |
+------------+--------+-----+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| 2015-06-04 | comA   | a1  | SUM of TIME for a1 for comA for the date in 'E_DATE' column |
| 2015-06-04 | comB   | a2  | SUM of TIME for a2 for comA for the date in 'E_DATE' column |
| 2015-06-04 | comB   | a3  | SUM of TIME for a3 for comA for the date in 'E_DATE' column |
| 2015-06-05 | comA   | a1  | SUM of TIME for a1 for comA for the date in 'E_DATE' column |
| 2015-06-05 | comA   | a2  | SUM of TIME for a2 for comA for the date in 'E_DATE' column |
| 2015-06-05 | comA   | a4  | SUM of TIME for a2 for comA for the date in 'E_DATE' column |
| 2015-06-05 | comB   | a1  | SUM of TIME for a1 for comA for the date in 'E_DATE' column |
+------------+--------+-----+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Is this the right query to achieve this?

```
select E_DATE, CLIENT,INS,SUM(INS) AS TOTAL_TIME GROUP BY E_DATE,CLIENT
```

Comment: Please note that you will get incorrect results if there are multiple `INS` values for the same `E_DATE` and `CLIENT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood it correctly then this should be the answer otherwise I/we will be needing the actual figures of `TOTAL_TIME` column in your expected result :

```
SELECT E_DATE,
       CLIENT,
       INS,
       (SELECT SUM(time)
        FROM   mytable b
        WHERE  a.E_DATE = b.E_DATE
               AND a.INS = b.INS
               AND b.CLIENT = 'comA') TOTAL_TIME
FROM   mytable a
GROUP  BY E_DATE,CLIENT,INS
```

NOTE : Assumed that `INS` in 2nd last row is `a4` as per logic.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/754c7/4)

Comment: Thank you Deepak. Will try & let you know.

Comment: Thank you Deepak for taking time off & work so much in depth. Appreciate & respect your efforts. Thank you again. Your solution too worked. I guess you've taken a different approach which is much more robust.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be:

```
select E_DATE, CLIENT, INS, SUM(TIME) AS TOTAL_TIME 
from Tablename
group by E_DATE, CLIENT, INS
```

Because in your example you are grouping by 3 columns `E_DATE, CLIENT, INS` and accumulating `TIME` column.

Comment: Thank you Giorgi. Will try & let you know.

Answer (score 1):

You should do *SUM(`TIME`)* rather like

```
select E_DATE, CLIENT,INS,SUM(`TIME`) AS TOTAL_TIME 
FROM mytable
GROUP BY E_DATE,CLIENT
```

Comment: Thank you Rahul. Will try & let you know.