# Hive - nested query

Tags: hive

I've totally new to hive. I've able to run non-nested SQL queries without a problem. However, I'm unable to execute the below query.

```
SELECT E_DATE,
       CLIENT,
       INS,
       (SELECT SUM(time)
        FROM   mytable b
        WHERE  a.E_DATE = b.E_DATE
               AND a.INS = b.INS
               AND b.CLIENT = 'comA') TOTAL_TIME
FROM   mytable a
GROUP  BY E_DATE,CLIENT,INS
```

I get the error FAILED: ParseException line 4:8 cannot recognize input near 'SELECT' 'SUM' '(' in expression specification

Comment: Hive doesn't support sub-queries in a `SELECT` statement.  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SubQueries

Comment: Hello - Thank you for pointing me there. Any suggestions on how I could convert the SQLquery into hive query please?

Comment: An example of what your data looks like and what you want to output to look like would be helpful.

Comment: Could I please ask you to refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31049397/sql-groupby-sum-of-a-column? THe table structure in there is what am after

Comment: There is a typo in that example (where did `a4` go?), scientific notation, and there's words for output ... I have no idea what the output should be.

Comment: How about the second answer in the question you link to : that one doesn't use a subselect

Comment: Hello GoBrewers - Yes there is a a4 in the output. It's a typo. With a4 in the output, would you be able to help me with the query please?

Comment: Hello Maxymoo - The second query works but I'd be interested to know how to get the nested query going please. The reason being, I've got a bunch of such nested SQL queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
select E_DATE,CLIENT,INS,SUM(time) 
from mytable 
where CLIENT = 'comA' 
group by E_DATE,CLIENT,INS;
```

OR

```sql
select a.E_DATE,a.CLIENT,a.INS,SUM(b.time)
from mytable a JOIN mytable b ON (a.E_DATE = b.E_DATE AND a.INS = b.INS)
where b.CLIENT = 'comA'
group by a.E_DATE,a.CLIENT,a.INS;
```

If you have a nested queries in sql, than in hive you have to go for joins to get the result.

Comment: Thank you heaps DRAGO. Appreciate your help :-)